# List C# (Unity) - can not add float values.

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I am trying to display best score in a `GameView`, but my way of doing it does not work.

I have a player that has to avoid obstacles, but when he fails to do so, he won't be able to move anymore and score counting will be terminated. Then, I would like to take that particular score and add it to my `List`.

However, in my code, no score is added, since whenever I start the game I get the `"Argument out of range"` error and if I run `Debug.Log` I can see there are no items in my list.

This is my code. (In this code I would only like to print the score that's on the first index, I would add `if conditions` later on for true best score). You should mostly focus to `void Start()` and first few lines of `void Update()`.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;

public class ScoreManager : MonoBehaviour {

    private float score = 0.0f;
    private int difficultyLevel = 1;
    private int scoreIncrementor = 1;
    private int maxdifficultyLevel = 10;
    private int scoreToNextLevel = 10;
    private bool isDead = false;
    private List<float> scoreBox;

    public Text scoreText;
    public Text bestScoreText;

    void Start(){
        scoreBox = new List<float> ();
        for(float i = 0; i <= scoreBox.Count; i++)
            bestScoreText.text = ("Best Score:  " + ((int)scoreBox [0]).ToString ());

    }


    void Update () {
        if (isDead) {
            scoreBox.Add (score);
            return;

        }
        if (score >= scoreToNextLevel)
            LevelUp ();
        score += Time.deltaTime;
        scoreText.text = ("Score: " + " "+ ((int)score).ToString ());
    }

    void LevelUp(){
        if (difficultyLevel == maxdifficultyLevel)
            return;

        scoreToNextLevel *= 2;
        difficultyLevel++;

        GetComponent<PlayerMovement> ().SetSpeed (scoreIncrementor);
    }

    public void OnDeath(){
        isDead = true;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem lies within the `Start()` method.

```
void Start(){
    scoreBox = new List<float> ();
    for(float i = 0; i <= scoreBox.Count; i++)
        bestScoreText.text = ("Best Score:  " + ((int)scoreBox [0]).ToString ());
}
```

You are creating a new list with no elements, then you are trying to display the results: But no element at position 0 exists, so you get a `IndexOutOfRange` excetpion.

Change the `<=` to `<` (remember, index starts at 0. But length starts at 1) and `scoreBox[0]` should be `scoreBox[i]`.

Also, may I ask why you make the list as `float` if you are casting it to `int` anyway?

Comment: Honestly, I've no idea, I started with int first, but then in a hope to get rid of an error, I started changing everything. I'll try this in a second

Comment: But that should not change anything right ? In that case, I only changed for loop condition and instead of first index, I take each on of them ? I should still get the same error.

Comment: No, you won't. The condition of the `for` loop is checked before entering the loop code, so when you create the List, it has `Count` equal to 0, thus the `i < scoreBox.Count` will return false, and you won't execute the code once.

Comment: @Seinfeld: If the list is `float` or `int` is indeed not important, it just doesn't make much sense to have a list in `float` if all you ever store is `int`. As for the loop, if you have no elements in the list, the for-loop will not execute with the changed condition. Since you want to display the max score, you should use `scoreBox.Max();`.